# Docker npm install not working, how can I solve?

Tags: node.js, docker

I extend my context because I need some file outside of Dockerfile directory.

This is my command :
docker build -f Dockerfile ../../
docker run (imageID)

file structure:

- model
- servers

  - subscribeship (I run docker command in this directory)

    - Dockerfile
    - index.js
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json

in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./servers/subscribeship/package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY ./servers/subscribeship .

COPY ./models ../../models

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

log for build image:

```
+] Building 7.5s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 231B                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:10                                                                                            2.7s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:10@sha256:59531d2835edd5161c8f9512f9e095b1836f7a1fcb0ab73e005ec46047384911                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                     1.3s
 => => transferring context: 23.27MB                                                                                                                  1.3s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [3/6] COPY ./servers/subscribeship/package*.json .                                                                                                0.1s
 => [4/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                             2.6s
 => [5/6] COPY ./servers/subscribeship .                                                                                                              0.4s
 => [6/6] COPY ./models ../../models                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                0.3s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                               0.3s 
 => => writing image sha256:9a87c205096b94e442a9f40e7c050ac68383f2da7fd8b285b5ee840c20f922af
```

log for run container:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/models/index.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

It seems like npm install not working.
package.json & package-lock.json indeed have sequelize package

[image]

I use same method for test if is my way wrong but it seems work..

I create another directory call bug, as same as servers level.
and then create bug1 directory inside bug folder like this:

command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile ../../
docker run (imageId)
```

- bug

  - bug1 (run command in here)

    - Dockerfile
    - package.json
    - pakcage-lock.json
    - .dockerignore

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./bug/bug1/package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY ./bug/bug1 .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

[image]

Comment: I am also kill my all image and container and volume. Also run docker builder prune

Comment: I think my method is right. Bc use the same method to do and it is work.

Answer (score 0):

`./` means you are navigating from the current directory. If you are running a command in `/servers/subscribeship`, `./` will refer to this directory. `./servers/subscribeship/package*.json` will then refer to `/servers/subscribeship/servers/subscribeship/package*.json`. Because this directory does not exist package.json is not copied and npm install will not install the required modules.

Comment: But I setting my context to ../../

Comment: COPY context(from) destination(container aka WORKDIR)

Comment: actually my original setting is use docker-compose file. I setting build context and dockerfile path

Comment: I change to root and run  docker build -f ./servers/subscribeship/Dockerfile . still not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
It turn out that model directory doesn't have package.json.